# Selenium - how to find elements by attribute with any value in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I know this way I can find element by attribute and value:

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//element[@someAttribute='someValue']"))
```

How can I find all elements that has the attribute `someAttribute` no matter what the value is?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `//element[@someAttribute]` for your XPath expression.