# Python Selenuim, finding a button with a specific attribute without XPATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script in Python using selenium that automates a store checkout. It launches to the site, finds the first item that matches the criteria, hits checkout, then proceeds top purchase. I am trying to find out how to make it select a specific color. The shop I am buying from updates the store every week with new items, so I won't have the XPATH available to me.

There is a button to change the color, and I need help being able to select the button.

The store has multiple buttons with the product in different colors as a way to choose between them.

**The button to change colors has ONE specific attribute titled "data-style-name"="(color)"**
[image]

I will not have any other attribute, link, or ID known to me, thus searching for this attribute seems like the only way to find it. The picture above is a snippet from pre-existing items on the storepage as an example.

(Note that above it says class="selected" because the "black" jacket has been clicked on while taking this screenshot. Example of a jacket that has not been clicked on:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas on the way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426645/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611503/selenium-how-to-find-elements-by-attribute-with-any-value-in-java), and a bit of reading up on [CSS selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) but something like:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-style-name]')
```

Might work for you